# Nuxt and Internet Explorer support (IE9)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I used `npx create-nuxt-app xxx` to create a demo and found that when launched under ie9, it refreshs infinitely. I did not changed any configuration.

I looked for a lot of documentation and I guess it's because of the router `history` mode. Because when I updated to `fallback: true`, it stopped refreshing infinitely.

Comment: you still use IE9 nowadays?

Comment: Indeed, IE11 is [officially dead](https://death-to-ie11.com/), Microsoft do not support it themselves. And, last stats that I found are saying that IE6-9 (4 versions combined so) are used for a total amount of `0.07%`. Safe to say that you could probably ditch IE9 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History mode is not compatible with older browsers (and IE9 is definitely one of them).

You'll need to use the `hash` mode or have full page refreshs.

Here is an official source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1675#issuecomment-321528860

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found the reason for this, but I don't know how to solve it in nuxt. My company hopes to be compatible with the best, I am not happy to be compatible with IE9.

Comment: @Zachary Internet Explorer is not supported by anybody anymore, not even Microsoft. So yeah, move on and let it just die haha.